# Launching Animations for Unity dock not working after installing Numix-Circle Icons

Tags: ubuntu, icons, themes, animation, ubuntu-unity

After installing Numix theme and Numix-Circle Icons there are no animations (pulse, jump, etc.) in the Unity dock even though the Unity Tweak Tool says they're activated. Any ideas on how to fix this?